# Problema para multiplicar los valores de mi array Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Buenas tardes me encuentro realizando varios ejercicios de practica que me dieron durante el año en la facultad y uno me costó algo de trabajo y aun así no creo que sea la forma más optima de resolverlo, Por eso pido a que me ayuden a buscar otro tipo de solución.
En el problema los datos que me dan son los siguientes:

- un array de números [6,2,8,5,1]
- un numero n = 10;

Lo que me pide es que muestre en consola una o mas  combinaciones de dos números del array que multiplicados entre si sean iguales a n

- Es un ejercicio que durante el año me había traído problemas y hoy lo resolví de la siguiente forma
  [El problema que me repite las combinaciones que encontro pero en distinto orden por ende me las duplica ejemplo: 7+3 = n y luego me cambia el orden : 3+7 = n], es por eso que estoy buscando una forma de simplificar este ejercicio:

```js
function operacion() {
  let numbers = [2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5];
  n = 10;
  numbers.forEach((value) => {
    const valor = value;
    for (element in numbers) {
      if (valor !== numbers[element] && valor * numbers[element] == n) {
        console.log(valor + " * " + numbers[element] + " = " + "10")
      } else {
        null
      }
    }
  });
}

operacion();
```

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 9):

Yo te recomiendo:

### Aprovecha que estás usando una función, usa parámetros de entrada

En vez de escribir valores fijos cómo:

```
let numbers = [2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5];
n = 10;
```

Dentro de tu función, utiliza parámetros, en este caso tienes una array y un número, esto te permitirá hacer tu código portable y poder reutilizarlo.

```
function operacion(miArray, n)
```

### Iteradores

Puedes iterar con un `for` o con un `forEach` ¿Porqué utilizas distintos métodos?¿Hay alguno que te permita obtener alguna ventaja?

### No necesitas reasignar variable

```
numbers.forEach((value) => {
    const valor = value;
```

Ya tienes el valor de `value` en lo que sigue del código (`scope`), no necesitas crear una nueva variable para guardar este valor.

### No compares valores, compara indices

```
valor * numbers[element] == n
```

Con un array=`[5,5]` y un n=`25` no tendrías ningún resultado porque estás comparando si los valores son iguales y estarías descartando una solución.

### Utiliza plantillas de literales

Te permiten dar fomato las strings de una manera más dinámica: [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings).

### Tomando todo esto en cuenta

Te ofrezco esta solución, en la cual las variables tienen nombres descriptivos, utiliza dos `forEach` y para no devolvernos a soluciones pasadas la comparación de los indices es `indiceA>=indiceB`, esto evitará duplicados.

```js
function operacion(miArray, n) {
  miArray.forEach((valorA, indiceA) => {
    miArray.forEach((valorB, indiceB) => {
      if(indiceA>=indiceB && valorA*valorB===n){
        console.log(`${valorA}*${valorB} = ${n}`);
      }
    });
  });
}

operacion([2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5],10);
```

Comment: Realmente me gusta como presentas tus respuestas. Ni tan largas, ni tan cortas. Buena tipografía que facilita la lectura y comprensión. Es un buen modelo a seguir.

Comment: @CandidMoe Muchas gracias Moe, es muy motivante recibir este tipo de comentarios de parte de alguien tan reconocido en el sitio.

Answer (score 6):

Tu problema es que estás recorriendo el array completo en ambos bucles; con ello, como dices, te sacará resultados duplicados.

Han de ser bucles distintos; en el exterior, recorres el array completo (*excepto el último*); en el interior, recorres desde la posición siguiente a la del bucle exterior:

```js
function operacion(numbers, n) {
  for (let idx = 0; idx < numbers.length - 1; ++idx) {
    for (let curr = idx + 1; curr < numbers.length; ++curr) {
      if (numbers[idx] * numbers[curr] == n) {
        console.log(numbers[idx], '*', numbers[curr], '==', n)
      }
    }
  }
}

let numbers = [2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5];
let n = 10;
operacion(numbers, n);
```

Como ves, no puedes usar `forEach( )`; tienes que recorrer el array basándote en el índice numérico.

Comment: +1, de esta forma no se compara 2 veces la misma combinación.

Comment: @Marcos Gracias por la edición, se me pasó puntualizar ese detalle :-)

Comment: En el primer for le pides que recorra el array completo menos el último ('numbers.length - 1'), porqué?

Comment: @CodexRex Porque el `for( )` interno **si** recorre hasta el último. Si no lo limito en el externo, el último ciclo de todos seria multiplicar el último por si mismo: los índices en ambos bucles estarían en el último elemento. Lo que sería multiplicar un elemento por si mismo, que *no vale*, puesto que ya no serían una multiplicación de 2 elementos.

Answer (score 2):

```
function operacion(numbers, n)
{
   var raiz = Math.sqrt(n);
   var i = 0;

   numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);

   while (numbers[i] <= raiz) 
   {
      if(n % numbers[i] == 0)
      {
         var d = n / numbers[i];
         
         if(numbers.includes(d, i)
         {
            console.log(numbers[i] + " * " + d + " = " + n);
         }             
      }

      i++;
   }
}
```

Pues bien, resulta que **todos los divisores de un número se hallan debajo de la raíz cuadrada de este**, por tanto hallamos la **raíz cuadrada de n** y posteriormente ordenamos el arreglo de forma ascendente, posteriormente ejecutamos un **ciclo while** que va a ejecutarse mientras el número actual del arreglo sea **<=** que la **raíz de n**. Si **n** es divisible por el elemento actual del arreglo entonces hacemos la división y buscamos si el resultado de esta división se encuentra en el arreglo mediante la **función include**. Si el resultado de esta división se encuentra en el arreglo entonces en el arreglo se encuentran dos números que multiplicados dan **n**, por tanto se imprimen estos números.

Es importante que el arreglo se ordene ya que esto reduce la comprobación de todos los números que **n** divide.

En vez de usar la **función include** también podrías haber usado la **función indexOf** la cual retorna el índice del elemento en caso de que se encuentre en el arreglo, en caso de que no se encuentre retorna **-1**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if(numbers.indexOf(2))
```

Busca el valor **2** dentro del **arreglo numbers**.

```
if(numbers.indexOf(2, 3))
```

Busca el valor **2** dentro del **arreglo numbers** a partir de la tercera posición del arreglo.